# Can this be solved for A?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve an equation and it has been a looong time since I've been in math class.

$$((c+r+a) - (c+.9r)) / (c+r+a) = 7\%$$

Can this be solved for $a$?

Thank you in advance

Gman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply both sides by (c+r+a) and expand, you end with a quadratic equation in "a". The solutions depends on both "c" and "r" because of the 0.9.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Is it possible to put the equation in a spreadsheet and calculate off of "c" and "r"  when they are valued?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28c%2Br%2Ba%29+-+%28c%2B.9r%29+%2F+%28c%2Br%2Ba%29+%3D+.07+for+a

Comment: Awsome site Amzoti, Thank you!! And Thank you Claude!

Comment: Did you change something to your post (adding some parenthese) ? If your problem is what it is now, what I told is wrong and, in this case, just follow what Justin wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, i think this is pretty simple, in stead of simplifying the top fraction by subtracting the c and r first divide by the bottom term to get rid of the top left term, then multiply both sides by that denominator then collect terms.

Comment: I think that the post changed ! If the problem is what we see now, you are perfectly write. If you check what Amzoti did with WA, this is what I answered. Cheers.